# npm install node-sqlserver failing on windows7

Tags: sql-server, node.js, node-sqlserver

Can you plese guide to resolve the error I am getting?

Ater running this on my local environment `npm install node-sqlserver`

I am getting this error at the end:

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\
npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:
12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modu
les\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Felipe\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sqlserver
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.24
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-sqlserver@0.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sqlserver@0.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sqlserver package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sqlserver
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "node-sqlserver" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd C:\
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.24
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

**Update 1**

All prerequisites has been run, this is occurs on the last step:

- Installed Python 2.7 http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.6/
- Then I installed `npm install -g node-gyp`
- Since I have VS.NET 2013 I did not had to install C++ Components or SQL Server Client
- `npm install node-sqlserver -g`

I also tried downlaoding the package from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29995

Comment: Are you able to install any other package? For example does npm install mongodb give any error?

Comment: yes, I installed express, karma, etc. I am running node just fine until now

Comment: I run the command in my cmd and I get an error as well. ( the same one to be more exact). I think as the error says that it might be a problem with the package. Also did you make sure that you have all of the prerequisites installed? The python in the class path? node-gyp? All of them are in the page of the repo in github

Comment: You can also download precompiled module from [node-sqlserver-binary](https://github.com/jorgeazevedo/node-sqlserver-binary).

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue as well. In the end I switched to this driver: https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments. Are you sure that you have all the prerequisites that the package needs?

**The following prerequisites are necessary prior to using the driver:**

Node.js - use the latest version if possible, but it has been tested on node 0.6.10 and later

node-gyp - latest version installed globally (npm install -g node-gyp)

python 2.7.x - for node-gyp (make sure it is in the path)

Visual C++ 2010 - the Express edition is freely available from Microsoft

SQL Server Native Client 11.0 - available as Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client found in the SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack

I took this from the github page.